# reverse engineering TP link TL-WR841N router

Tags: firmware

I am trying to reverse engineer my routers firmware. So as the first step I took uart pins and I could login to the router through serial console. I need to export the binary files to my host system. My host PC is running ubuntu. I have tried SSH login but I am not able to login as the username and password is unknown. Also username and password is required for SCP too. So how can I copy files to host? Please suggest any method. How should I approach this situation?

Comment: Can't you just download the firmware from the vendor website? Since you have access, can't you change passwords? There are many ways to copy files over a text-only channel using different encodings.

Comment: As i have access i could change the password through webui. But ssh is not possible with those credentials. When i enter the password it is showing as incorrect. How to find root password. I have serial console access too.

Comment: Just like any Linux box, check `/etc/passwd` and/or `/etc/shadow`.